# PHP Login with Textfile

Tags: php, html, forms

How to show data in row by row for every users in textfiles after they filled out data from a form?
My data should be like example below
Example output in Text File:

```
Username: ABC Password: 123
Username: DEF Password: 456
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$username = $password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
<h2>How to show data in row by row for every users in textfiles after they filled out data from a form?</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$myfile = fopen("login.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo "<h2>Username:</h2>";
fwrite($myfile, $name);
echo "<br><h2>Password:</h2>";
fwrite($myfile, $password);
echo "<br><br>";
fclose($myfile);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you showing multiple users login and password details in a text file? Are you trying to output breached data from your office?

Comment: I mean the output should not be every info in a same row. I mean my output wants to make based on example above for output in the text file. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Martin, if more than one user are login or register, text file will store more than one user in every row per user login or register. By the way, what is the meaning of breached data?

Comment: breached  == a compromised system,  website or database from which data has been stolen

Comment: Can you clarify your question: are you trying to SAVE data to the text file or trying to READ data from the textfile?

Comment: I am trying to save and read data from the text file. By the way, mamta has answered my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also your `fwrite` code should be inside of `if statement`

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $username = $password = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);

    $myfile = fopen("login.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, "Username :" . $name." "."Password :".$password."\r\n");
   fclose($myfile);
    }
    ?>
    <h2>How to show data in row by row for every users in textfiles after they filled out data from a form?</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I have used `\r\n` for a new line beacause you have text file.

Comment: mamta, this is the one I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, ignoring the fact that the content you are playing with appears to be somewhat suspect and at best, bad programming practise:

### Qualifiers

- `echo` will output to the screen and not to the text file.
- `fwrite` will write to the file but will not output to the screen.
- Note you should put a full path to your text file if it's not in the same directory as your PHP file.
- Password data should ***ALWAYS*** be hashed, never kept as plaintext values.

### To Save Data

To save the data string to the file you can use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
... 
(rest of file)  
</form>
</body>
</html>
$data = "Username: ".$name." Password: ".$password.PHP_EOL; 
// PHP_EOL is a system specific end of line marker. 
// Alternative is to use the "\n" marker,
file_put_contents("login.txt",$data,FILE_APPEND) or die("Unable to save to file!");
```

And that's it, the value of `$data` is appended to the end of the text file. If you do not want to append the data and instead *overwrite* the data in the file simply remove the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

### To Read Data

You want to use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to easily load up the data, and then you can split it into an array using `explode` to read each line as its own value (optional, but recommended), then  you can output that value using [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to work on each row of the file (`array`):

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents("login.txt") or die("Unable to open file!");
$fileLines = explode(PHP_EOL,$fileContents);
foreach($fileLines as $line){
    //line now displays the data from the file, line by line. 
    print $line."<br>"; // this will output said data.
}
unset($line);
```